# Create an access an API from blazor server in blazor client using .net 8 auto project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to access a function in my c# code that resides on the server from the client. I have a controller on the server that looks like this:

```
using LottoPicker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace LottoPicker.Controllers.Lotto;

[Route("api/Lotto")]
[ApiController]
public class LottoGeneratorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<List<int>>> GetCombinations()
    {
        LottoGenerator lottoGenerator = new LottoGenerator();
        return lottoGenerator.GetCombinations();
    }
}
```

My razor page on the client side:

```
@page "/lotto"
@using System.Net.Http
@inject HttpClient Http
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<h3>Lotto</h3>


@code {
    List<List<int>>? combinations;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        combinations = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<List<int>>>("api/Lotto");
    }
}
```

And then my program.cs for the client:

```
using LottoPicker.Client.Pages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

But when I go to the lotto page I get the error:

> InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'Http'
> on type 'LottoPicker.Client.Pages.Lotto'. There is no registered
> service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory+<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, IComponent component)

And some extra error info:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property
> 'Http' on type 'LottoPicker.Client.Pages.Lotto'. There is no
> registered service of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'.    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Initialize|1(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, IComponent component)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider
> serviceProvider, Type componentType, IComponentRenderMode
> callerSpecifiedRenderMode, Nullable`1 parentComponentId)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame[] frames, Int32 frameIndex, Int32 parentComponentId)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 frameIndex)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 newFrameIndex)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& diffContext, Int32 oldStartIndex, Int32 oldEndIndexExcl, Int32 newStartIndex, Int32 newEndIndexExcl)    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer renderer, RenderBatchBuilder batchBuilder, Int32 componentId, ArrayRange`1 oldTree, ArrayRange`1 newTree)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder
> batchBuilder, RenderFragment renderFragment, Exception&
> renderFragmentException)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.AddToRenderQueue(Int32
> componentId, RenderFragment renderFragment)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.StateHasChanged()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallOnParametersSetAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.SetDirectParameters(ParameterView
> parameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderRootComponentAsync(Int32
> componentId, ParameterView initialParameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HtmlRendering.Infrastructure.StaticHtmlRenderer.BeginRenderingComponent(IComponent
> component, ParameterView initialParameters)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.EndpointHtmlRenderer.RenderEndpointComponent(HttpContext
> httpContext, Type rootComponentType, ParameterView parameters, Boolean
> waitForQuiescence)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Endpoints.RazorComponentEndpointInvoker.RenderComponentCore(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<b__10_0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---    at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

I'm not quite sure where to go from here, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So after some (lots) of digging, I found my solutions.

```
using LottoPicker.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace LottoPicker.Controllers.Lotto;

[Route("api/[controller]")] // changed from [Route("api/Lotto")]
[ApiController]
public class LottoGeneratorController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<List<int>>> GetCombinations()
    {
        LottoGenerator lottoGenerator = new LottoGenerator();
        return lottoGenerator.GetCombinations();
    }
}
```

```
using LottoPicker.Client.Pages;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) }); // this whole line can be deleted, the code is a bit different and needs to be placed in the server program.cs

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

program.cs for server:

```
using LottoPicker.Client.Pages;
using LottoPicker.Components;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerClient", client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7061/");
}); //this needed to be added

builder.Services.AddControllers(); // this needed to be added

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.MapControllers(); // this needed to be added

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(LottoPicker.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.Run();
```

and then in my actual razor file on the client needed to look like this:

```
@page "/lotto"
@using System.Net.Http
@rendermode InteractiveAuto
@inject IHttpClientFactory ClientFactory //add this

@code {
    List<List<int>>? combinations;
    private HttpClient _client; // add this

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _client = ClientFactory.CreateClient("ServerClient");
    } // add this

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        combinations = await _client.GetFromJsonAsync<List<List<int>>>("api/LottoGenerator"); // make sure this is the name of you Controller file minus the "Controller" part
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).